# Parsing Semantic Version using Antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar, bnf, semantic-versioning

I translated the [SemVer 2 BNF grammar](https://semver.org/#backusnaur-form-grammar-for-valid-semver-versions) to the following Antlr grammar.

```
grammar SemVer;

@header {
package com.me.semver;
}

semVer : normal ('-' preRelease)? ('+' build)? ;
normal : major '.' minor '.' patch ;
major : NUM ;
minor : NUM ;
patch : NUM ;
preRelease : PRE_RELEASE ('.' preRelease)* ;
build : BUILD ('.' build)*;
NUM : '0'
    | POSITIVE_DIGIT
    | POSITIVE_DIGIT DIGITS
    ;
BUILD : ALPHANUM
      | DIGITS
      ;
PRE_RELEASE : ALPHANUM
            | NUM
            ;
fragment
ALPHANUM : NON_DIGIT
         | NON_DIGIT CHARS
         | CHARS NON_DIGIT
         | CHARS NON_DIGIT CHARS
         ;
fragment
CHARS : CHAR+ ;
fragment
CHAR : DIGIT
     | NON_DIGIT
     ;
fragment
NON_DIGIT : LETTER
          | '-'
          ;
fragment
DIGITS : DIGIT+ ;
fragment
DIGIT : '0'
      | POSITIVE_DIGIT
      ;
fragment
POSITIVE_DIGIT : [1-9] ;
fragment
LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

But parsing `1.0.0-beta+exp.sha.5114f85` gives the following error:

> line 1:4 mismatched input '0-beta' expecting NUM

The output from the listener is as follows:

```
Normal: 1.0.0-beta
Major: 1
Minor: 0
Patch: 0-beta
Build: exp.sha.5114f85
Build: sha.5114f85
Build: 5114f85
```

Clearly, the patch version is not what it should be. The correct output would have `Patch = 0`, `Pre release = beta`, and `Build = exp.sha.5114f85`.

How can I fix the grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many overlapping lexer rules. For example, the input `0` could be matched by any of the following 3 rules:

```
NUM : '0'
    | POSITIVE_DIGIT
    | POSITIVE_DIGIT DIGITS
    ;
BUILD : ALPHANUM
      | DIGITS
      ;
PRE_RELEASE : ALPHANUM
            | NUM
            ;
```

and since `NUM` is placed first, the input `0` will always become a `NUM` token. It doesn't matter what token the parser is trying to match, it will always be a `NUM` token.

This is just how ANTLR's lexer works:

1. it tries to match as much characters as possible for each token, and
2. when two or more lexer rules match the same amount of characters, the one defined first "wins".

Given your grammar and the input `"1.0.0-beta+exp.sha.5114f85"`, these tokens are created:

```
NUM                       `1`
null                      `.`
NUM                       `0`
null                      `.`
BUILD                     `0-beta`
null                      `+`
BUILD                     `exp`
null                      `.`
BUILD                     `sha`
null                      `.`
BUILD                     `5114f85`
```

Notice the `0-beta` is being tokenized as a single `BUILD` token (rule  #1).

What you should do is define lexer rules that do not overlap. In your case, that would mean defining these rules/tokens:

```
HYPHEN
 : '-'
 ;

PLUS
 : '+'
 ;

DOT
 : '.'
 ;

ZERO_DIGIT
 : '0'
 ;

POSITIVE_DIGIT
 : [1-9]
 ;

LETTER
 : [a-zA-Z]
 ;
```

and a rule like `DIGIT` and `DIGITS` would then become a parser rules instead:

```
digits
 : digit+
 ;

digit
 : ZERO_DIGIT
 | POSITIVE_DIGIT
 ;
```

Comment: I've several follow up questions.
1. A `non-digit` is a `letter` and `-`; you seem to have replaced `non-digit` with `LETTER`, that's incorrect.
2. Numeric identifiers in a pre-release version [must not include leading zeroes](https://semver.org/#spec-item-9); however, no such restriction is placed on the numeric identifiers for build metadata. This subtle distinction is absent for your grammar (I think that's why the BNF used `digits ` and `numeric identifier` separately).
3. What is the difference between your `valid_semver` rule and my `semVer` rule (I'm not an Antlr expert)?

Comment: (Since I exceeded comment length above)...4. Why create aliases like `build : dot_separated_build_identifiers`? A more common sense approach seems to rename `dot_separated_build_identifiers` and just use it.

Comment: I removed the grammar and emphasized the actual problem in your grammar.